# Python - requests, lmxl and xpath not working

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, python-requests

I am trying to write some python to scrape the web for firmware/driver updates but different web pages are responding differently.

I've used the requests and lxml packages to find the information based on xpath.  Xpath was found by opening URL in chrome, right clicking on the data and inspecting it, then right click again when it is showing the code and selecting copy xpath.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**
Intel NUC at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/76977/Intel-NUC-Kit-D54250WYK.
At 2019-12-25 the data value it correctly picks up is "24.3".

```py
import requests
from lxml import html 
url="https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/76977/Intel-NUC-Kit-D54250WYK"
page = requests.get(url)
XpathToFWtype = '//*[@id="search-results"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/text()'
tree.xpath(XpathToFWtype)
```

**FAILING EXAMPLE**
Similar logic fails for ASUS website, where it should scape firmware text **Version 1.1.2.3_790**:
https://www.asus.com/lk/Networking/DSL-AC56U/HelpDesk_BIOS/

The failing xpath returns from inspect statement as:

```
//*[@id="Manual-Download"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[1]span[1]
```

Everything I try fails, whether I add "/text()" or any variation.  The webpages differ in that the "view source" shows the text for the Intel url, and not the Asus so it is being dynamically generated somewhere - but I am unsure after days of trying everything what to do next.

```py
import requests
from lxml import html
url="https://www.asus.com/lk/Networking/DSL-AC56U/HelpDesk_BIOS/"
page = requests.get(url)
XpathToFWtype = '//*[@id="Manual-Download"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/text()'
tree.xpath(XpathToFWtype)
#  etc -> many traceback errors from lxml :-(
```

Thanks for any suggestion or direction, its really appreciated

Comment: seems that you aren't aware that `ASUS` website is loaded via `JavaScript` which `requests` module will not be able to render it, are you looking to retrieve the download size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `INTEL` website you can do the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/76977/Intel-NUC-Kit-D54250WYK")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("td", {'class': 'dc-version collapsible-col collapsible1'}):
    item = item.text
    print(item[0:item.find("L")])
```

Output:

```
24.3
0054
1.0.0
6.1.9
15.40.41.5058
1.01
1
6.0.1.7982
11.0.6.1194
15.36.28.4332
15.40.13.4331
15.36.26.4294
14.5.0.1081
2.4.2013.711
10.1.1.8
10.0.27
2.4.2013.711
2.4.2013.711
```

For `ASUS` website it's actually using `JavaScript` to render it's content. so you will need to use `Selenium` or `PhantomJS`. but I've been able to locate the `XHR` to the `JSON` `API` and called it by a request :).

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.asus.com/support/api/product.asmx/GetPDBIOS?website=lk&pdhashedid=RtHWWdjImSzhdG92&model=DSL-AC56U&cpu=").json()

for item in r['Result']['Obj']:
    for data in item['Files']:
        print(data['Version'])
```

Output:

```
1.1.2.3_790
1.1.2.3_743
1.1.2.3_674
1.1.2.3_617
1.1.2.3_552
1.1.2.3_502
1.1.2.3_473
```

> You can parse whatever from here :) https://www.asus.com/support/api/product.asmx/GetPDBIOS?website=lk&pdhashedid=RtHWWdjImSzhdG92&model=DSL-AC56U&cpu=

Comment: That's amazing, you can parse everything from that!  Thanks so much.  Is it too complex to explain how you got to the XHR query?

Comment: @far you welcome, glad to help. you can get the `XHR` request via your browser `developer-tools` and by checking the `network-tab`. let me know if you need screenshot.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your patience and assistance @ahmed!  I've found the `network-tab`, and then the `XHR` line you identified.  But opening that URL had error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` until I dropped the last parameter from URL to make it the same as you => removed the final text from the URL being `&callback=supportpdpage`.  Is it just experience that you knew to remove that bit?

Comment: @far almost welcome, that's called [JSONP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp) `call back` Which is very old technique, used `for sending JSON data without worrying about cross-domain issues.`

Comment: @ahmed thanks so much for the help and direction to understand more, it's really appreciated